# latex стал отображать пробельные символы

Tags: latex

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Латех посредине кода начал отображать пробельные символы,как это пофиксить

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: Без кода документа сложно сказать, где Вы накосячили. Но есть подозрение, что Вы использовали вариант окружения для вывода кода со звездочкой или в настройках стилей пакета (это listings?) попросили его графически отображать пробелы.